# Can't create tag <tbody> in <table> tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table showing file information for members after uploading. However, for some reasons, the  tag causes the layout to be deflected.

When I open the F12 window, my code is as shown below:

[image: F12]

The problem lies in the  tag and the  tag conjoined together.

[image: sticky]

Now, I just edit it by adding a space marker or a line delimiter:

[image: line delimiter]

Immediately, it creates another  tag and contains the entire ,  tag inside. Interface restored, no more errors!

Here is my entire source code:

```
<table id="files" class="files table table-striped" width="100%"></table>
var isSuccess = true;
if(data['result'][0]['error'] != null)
{
 isSuccess = false;
}
var html = ''; // I tried adding the <tbody></tbody> tag here but 
               // it still needs a space or line break -> not working!

html += '<tr class="template-download';
if(isSuccess == false)
{
    html += ' errorText';
}
html += '" ';
if(isSuccess == true)
{
    html += 'onClick="return showAdditionalInformation(this);"';
}
html += '>';

if(isSuccess == true)
{
    html += data['result'][0]['success_result_html'];
}
else
{
    html += data['result'][0]['error_result_html'];
}
html += '</tr>';

function handleUrlUploadSuccess(data)
{
    isSuccess = true;
    if(data.error != null)
    {
        isSuccess = false;
    }
    html = '';
    html += '<tr class="template-download';
    if(isSuccess == false)
    {
        html += ' errorText';
    }
    html += '" onClick="return showAdditionalInformation(this);">'
    if(isSuccess == false)
    {
        // add result html
        html += data.error_result_html;
    }
    else
    {
        // add result html
        html += data.success_result_html;
        // keep a copy of the urls globally
        fileUrls.push(data.url);
        fileDeleteHashes.push(data.delete_hash);
        fileShortUrls.push(data.short_url);
    }
    html += '</tr>';
    $('#rowId'+data.rowId).replaceWith(html);
    if(data.rowId == urlList.length-1)
    {
        // show footer
        $('#urlUpload .urlFileListingWrapper .processing-button').addClass('hidden');
        $('#urlUpload .fileSectionFooterText').removeClass('hidden');
        // set additional options
        sendAdditionalOptions();
        // setup copy link
        setupCopyAllLink();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're saying the problem is, and the question doesn't contain all the relevant source code. However, you should be using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create the HTML instead of strings.

Comment: Where are you adding the `tr` to the table?

Comment: @Herohtar, DOM manipulation comes at a cost. Sometimes it is actually more efficient to work with strings and add with `innerHTML`

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE]. It is much easier for us to help if we have enough code to replicate the issue. By minimizing the problem it makes it easier to pinpoint the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

The start of your loop or javascript should just be the open  tag and not the close.  At the end of the loop/javascript you should have the close tag.  They should be wrapping all of the table row tags being created.

Comment: Assuming there is a loop, which is not apparent in the OPs code.

Comment: @JonP Agreed.  Lots of assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using a single string for your row template then use `replace` to update it

```js
var html = ''; 
//Template for our row
var row = "<tr class='template-download{{additionalClasses}} {{onClick}}>{{data}}</tr>"

//Dummy Data
var isSuccess = true;
var data = {
  result : [{
      success_result_html: "<td>Success</td>",
      error_result_html: "<td>Fail</td>"
  }]
};

//Populate row depending on condition
if(isSuccess)
{
  html = row.replace("{{additionalClasses}}","")
            .replace("{{onClick}}", "onClick='return showAdditionalInformation(this);'")
            .replace("{{data}}", data['result'][0]['success_result_html']);
}
else
{
  html = row.replace("{{additionalClasses}}"," errorText")
            .replace("{{onClick}}", "")
            .replace("{{data}}", data['result'][0]['error_result_html']);
}
//Add the row to the tbody
document.querySelector("#files tbody").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<table id="files" class="files table table-striped" width="100%">
  <!-- Add tbody here-->
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't uploaded enough code! I've updated, please help me!